# Does server fault have an app like stack over flow?

Tags: discussion

It would come in handy for server administrators like me who ask and answer questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Please read the help center before posting anything. And yes, apps for StackExchange (including SF) exists. Search on your platforms app store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an app.

[image: Get it on Google Play] [image: Download on the App Store]